# SQL Distinct Left Join

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I have an issue where I'm trying to find a distinct value from my main table where a text value from a different column in t2 doesn't exist. E.G.

```
   SELECT t1.val, t2.desc
     FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 
       On t1.val = t2.val
      And t2.desc NOT LIKE 'some text'
```

The problem I'm having is I'm retrieving duplicate values for t1.val because t2.desc has other variable values than 'some text'.

Distinct doesn't work becaue the t2.desc is text and not comparable.

I've trawled through several other questions that appeared to be similar but couldn't find one that fit my criteria.

I've been trying to get this working all morning and would really appreciate the assist on getting the distinct values from t1.

Thanks

having tried the suggestions I'm still seeing multiples of t1.val in the output

```
  t1.Val  t2.[desc]
  1811352  Process
  1811352  Conversion
  1811352  State
  1811352  Test
  1811352  Work
```

The desired output I'm looking for is a single t1.val where there isn't a value for a specific text in t2.[desc]. Hence trying to get a disctinct t1.val where the t2.[desc] specific text doesn't appear anywhere in t2.[desc].

So in the example above I'd like to see 1811352 once because it doesn't contain the t2.[desc] "some text"

Comment: Why you want to use left join?
Inner join can help

Comment: Editing your question to show some sample data, the output you're getting, and the output you want will go a long way toward getting you some more help on this. This page might be useful for formatting your data. https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Answer (score 0):

if what you need is to take distinct based on Val only, try this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.val ORDER BY t1.val),
       t1.val,
       t2.[desc]
       FROM t1
          LEFT JOIN t2 
             ON t1.val = t2.val
                AND t2.[desc] NOT LIKE 'some text'
)
SELECT
    val,
    [desc]
    FROM CTE
       WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `TEXT`  data type, it has been deprecated long back. Instead of this you should use `VARCHAR(MAX)`

Quick solution when you can't change it as `VARCHAR(MAX)`, you can `CAST` it to `VARCHAR(MAX)` and apply a `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.val, CAST(t2.[desc] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.val = t2.val
AND t2.[desc] NOT LIKE 'some text'
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail, I did the update and now I assume I get distinct rows for t2.[Desc] as the output shows multiple from t1.val?

Comment: Do you want only one t2.Desc to appear, if yes which one, what is the criteria? Please add the desired output also in the question. It will help

Answer (score 0):

I think I eventually got what I was looking for with the following:

```
SELECT t1.val
     FROM t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT t2.[desc] FROM t2 WHERE t1.val = t2.val
      And t2.[desc] LIKE 'some text')
```

Really appreciate the responses.

Thanks